# Random scheduling of backups in BareOS

Tags: backup, scheduled-task, bacula, bareos

I've recently configured the laptops and workstations in my environment with BareOS. We are doing this as a preventative measure for data loss (part of a grander scheme of recommendations). With the large-ish number of them available, they're not always on the network (mostly laptops).

I'm wondering if there's a way in BareOS to check for a system being online and backing it up on a semi-random basis. Is this a custom scripting thing? If so, has anyone done anything like this?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a python script that runs via cron.  You can see my code here  [on Github](https://github.com/lgwapnitsky/misc_scripting/blob/master/bareos/bareosClientStatusCheck.py)